# Make variable doesn't evaluate

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to evaluate a make variable which name is stored in another variable but it is not evaluating. Below is simplified version of my problem:

```
VAR=MYDEV
MYDEV_init=UART_init


define create_kernels_c
    dev=$$(echo MYDEV);  #this is mandatory code, simplified here
    echo dev = $$dev;
    initfn=$$dev\_init;
    echo initfn= $$initfn
    devinit=$($$initfn)
    echo devinit= $$devinit
endef


.ONESHELL:
all:
    @$(call create_kernels_c)
```

I want to evaluate $$devinit to UART_init, but it is not evaluating. What mistake I am making in my code?

Comment: `MYDEV` is a make variable which is not known to the shell. Use `export` directive and read the relevant chapter from the make's manual carefully.

Comment: Also, it's best to implement a new technique *in isolation* as much as possible. You're trying to implement it in the middle of some string manipulation inside a recipe template (both of which are incorrect).